# python 'bool' object is not callable'

Tags: python, com

I have seen a few other similar questions, unfortunately none quite solved my issue. my codes are pretty extensive so not going to paste everything here. my python script is running an excel and a macro within. its does all the fine but when it comes to saving the file down I get the error. I have shown snippets of my codes below. any idea what seems to be happening? it sporadically works well and randomly stops working.

```
import win32com.client
import time
from datetime import datetime

    def openWorkbook(xlapp, xlfile,upDateLink,openReadOnly,wbVisible):
        try:
            xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks(xlfile,upDateLink,openReadOnly,wbVisible) # the 2nd is for updatelink, 3rd is for OpenReadOnly
        except Exception as e:
            try:
                print('run function')
                xlapp.Workbooks.Open('C:\\blp\\API\\Office Tools\\BloombergUI.xla')
                xlapp.RegisterXLL('C:/blp/API/Office Tools/bofaddin.dll')
                xlwb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(xlfile,upDateLink,openReadOnly) # the 2nd is for updatelink, 3rd is for OpenReadOnly
                xlapp.Visible = wbVisible

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                xlwb = None
        return(xlwb)

wb1 = openWorkbook(xlapp, filepath,False,True,wbVisible)

filepathSaveStress = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\Projects\\Stress" + extractDate2 + ".xlsm"


print('run CalculateValues')
xlapp.Application.run("CalculateValues")
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False

if stresstype == 'Stress':
        wb1.SaveAs(filepathSaveStress)
else:
        wb1.SaveAs(filepathSavePostStress)
```

not sure why it errors out at `wb1.SaveAs(filepathSaveStress)`

in term or error all I get is this

```
'bool' object is not callable
```

Comment: add the error pls with the traceback

Comment: Without the error traceback, not just the exception, it will be impossible to determine which statement is failing and how the program got there. Without it, my presumption is that `wb1.SaveAs` is a boolean value rather than the method you appear to believe it is. Since `wb1` appears with no explanation, we have no idea what type of object it is, or what its API might be ...

Comment: added a few more lines to the original code

Comment: strangely when I run it in the debug mode it saves the file fine.